# get URL of network requests displayed by the Developer Tools in the Network panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I’d like to get URL of network requests displayed by the Developer Tools in the Network panel that match some pattern (e.g. ends with .aac)in a Chrome extension. 
 It seems I can use the chrome.devtools.network API to achieve it, but that way seems  requires the Developer Tools window to be open for the extension to work, not so convenient !!!

Is there another way to fulfill this task ?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities.

First, and easier, you can employ [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), and listen to `onBeforeRequest` event:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { console.log(details.url); },
  {urls: ["*://*/*.aac"]}
);
```

Second, if you need *exactly* the same information as presented by Dev Tools, there is [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger), that allows you to attach to a tab in place of Dev Tools using the [debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol).

It's harder, as the debugger protocol documentation is not easy to find and read. Also, a caveat: only one tool can use debugger protocol, so if you open Dev Tools, `chrome.debugger` will be disconnected.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Fixed. Feel free to apply such minor edits yourself, now that you have the rep.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I've seen that there's only a callback argument defined for the `onBeforeRequest.addListener` method, and if you call it without the second argument (the filter), you'll get `Uncaught Error: Parameter 1 (filter) is required`. So were (and how) did you find that second parameter that isn't stated in the [documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest)? And, more important, what are the filters you can apply with that argument?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It's stated [earlier on the page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription). _"To register an event listener for a web request, you use a variation on the usual `addListener()` function. In addition to specifying a callback function, you have to specify a filter argument and you may specify an optional extra info argument."_ The documentation you're pointing at tells of one argument to the handler itself, not `addListener()`.

Comment: I don't want the Developer Tools window to be open for the extension to work,so chrome.debugger API may not the one I needed here ,as for the webRequest API, it works well for my case, I encounter another problem :If I added console.log("page title:"+document.title); before console.log(details.url); in the function ,document.title just return none ,is there any way to figure it out ?

Comment: `chrome.debugger` works if, and only if, the Developer Tools window is _closed_.

Comment: @Xan, Are they ever going to fix this bug and change the text to `Parameter 2 (filter)` instead?